# localtime() - segmentation fault

Tags: c, fault, localtime

I have this code that return the week day from a date like "29-02-2016", but sometimes it gives me segmentation fault in localtime(&t).

```
int obterDiaSemana(char *str) {
 struct tm tm2;
 if(strptime(str, "%d-%m-%Y", &tm2) != NULL) {
  time_t t = mktime(&tm2);
  return localtime(&t)->tm_wday; //Sunday=0, Monday=1, etc.
 }
 return -1;
}
```

the function receives:

```
 char userDate[10]="29-02-2016";
```

I've been looking for a solution but cant solve this.

Thanks in advance.

If you need some additional info just let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not initializing `struct tm tm2`. When it is passed to strptime, only members specified in the format string `"%d-%m-%Y"` are set with values, others are left unchanged, in this case uninitialized, so their values are indeterminate.

Passing that partially initialized struct `tm2` to mktime() will result in undefined behavior.

You will need to initialize the struct with some values, preferably with zeroes.

---

And array userDate is too small to contain `"29-02-2016"`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. ill vote your answer when I have permission to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems in this code: You don't initialize tm2, so it may hold any values. If mktime does not like its parameter it will return (time_t)-1. Calling `localtime((time_t)-1)` seems to crash with a segfault.

You should initialize `tm2` and check if `localtime` returns -1.

Comment: Thanks for the help. ill vote your answer when I have permission to do it.