# Negative time conversion gives random values

Tags: c, time, initialization, undefined-behavior, integer-overflow

I'm trying to calculate a difference between two points in time in C and because those points are before 1900, I need to use negative values.

While converting is supposed to write the variable `jahr_tod_negative` into `ts.tm_year`, but almost every time I run the program, it gives me a completely different date, even day and month are mixed up. The year is the only value that needs to be negative. How can I prevent that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{

    time_t t;
    struct tm ts;
    char str[90];

    int tag_tod;
    int monat_tod;
    int jahr_tod;
    unsigned int jahr_tod_von_1900;
    int jahr_tod_negative;


    printf("Tag eingeben: ");
    scanf("%d", &tag_tod);
    printf("\nMonat eingeben: ");
    scanf("%d", &monat_tod);
    printf("\nJahr eingeben: ");
    scanf("%d", &jahr_tod);
    jahr_tod_von_1900 = 1900 - jahr_tod;
    jahr_tod_negative = -jahr_tod_von_1900;
    printf("jahr_tod_negative: %d\n", jahr_tod_negative);


    //ts.tm_sec     = 0;
    //ts.tm_min     = 0;
    //ts.tm_hour  = 0;
    ts.tm_mday  = tag_tod;
    ts.tm_mon   = monat_tod;
    ts.tm_year  = jahr_tod_negative;     /* Jahr - 1900 */
    //ts.tm_wday  = 0;
    //ts.tm_yday  = 0;
    //ts.tm_isdst = 0;

    t = mktime(&ts);
    //printf("%s", asctime(&ts));
    printf("ts.tm_year: %d\n", ts.tm_year);
    strftime(str, 90, "%d. %B %Y", &ts);
    printf("Eingegebenes Datum: %s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Who told you this is supposed to work? I am not sure at all but I fear it cannot.

Comment: @jdarthenay About 4/10 times it outputs the right value, the other 6 times it seems randomized.

Comment: This is interesting.  It's good to get a chance to UPvote a question for a change:)

Comment: Can you give the inputs you are using? Also precise if you are building 32bits or 64bits programs.

Comment: @jdarthenay tried inputs: e.g. 1456 (works), 1568 (random numbers), every number larger than 1900 outputs the right value. It's 64 bit btw.

Comment: Please give us **full** input (not only the year) and edit your question to put that, because this should be part of your question.

Comment: 1/1/1456 works; 1/8/1567 outputs ts.tm_year 98432 and 05. November 100332 as final output.

Comment: This is weird, I don't have the bug you have. What is your compiler?

Comment: Consider running your code inside a debugger, tracing through it step by step while inspecting all relevant variables, to what is really going on.

Comment: clang, I'm using OS X 10.10.5.

Comment: Also, not at all answering the question, but you can add `#include <locale.h>` and start `main()` with `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` to get a date text in your native language.

Comment: Doesn't signed integer over-/underflow trigger undefined behaviour?

Comment: Indeed, I hope you tried Henno's answer, just to be sure.

Comment: This question is related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/35536990/694576 if not a duplicate to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For starters: You want to properly initialise

```
struct tm ts;
```

before using it. Else the code might very well run into *undefined behaviour*, so anything can happen.

Do

```
struct tm ts = {0};
```

at least.

---

Furthermore assuming

```
unsigned int jahr_tod_von_1900;
int jahr_tod_negative;
```

this statement

```
 jahr_tod_von_1900 = 1900 - jahr_tod;
```

cause a `signed` integer wrap around for `jahr_tod > 1900`. This latter "overflow" causes *undefined behaviour* as well then. Do ***not*** do this.

As you are assigning to an `unsigned` anyway, to fix this make sure you do an "unsigned" subtraction like for example this way:

```
jahr_tod_von_1900 = 1900U - (unsigned int) jahr_tod;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem (among possibly other things) lies in

`jahr_tod_von_1900 = 1900 - jahr_tod;`

where you declare:

`unsigned int jahr_tod_von_1900;`

What happens if `jahr_tod` is actually larger than `1900`? You implicitly convert a negative value to an unsigned integer and so you get a very large value, usually.

If I throw away all the jahr_tod_negative stuff, and just use (once!)

`ts.tm_year = jahr_tod - 1900;`

I always get the right answer.

Comment: Values greater than 1900 give the right output, because the positive value is added to 1900.

Comment: Guessing in an answer mostly does not help. With this is tends to make an answer a low quality answer ... :-( If unsure, better post a comment.

Comment: @alk  I tried my solution :even without initialisation it worked on OS X. So the overflow was an issue

Comment: I do not argue against what you wrote regarding "overflows", but how you wrote it (--> "*I think*"). If not sure do not answer. Easy! ;-)

Comment: And BTW "*... cast a negative value to an unsigned ...*": the OP's code does not cast anywhere. It invokes *implicit conversion*, which is not the same.

Comment: @alk, OK, I first wrote my supposition, Then I compiled the code as it was, and tried my rewrite, which then gave the correct results. It's true he doesn't cast, bad terminology...